# How to open a very large GeoJSON file with Geopandas.read_file() without lengthy pause?

Tags: python, filesystems, geopandas

I'm trying to efficiently iterate through the features of very large geojson files (2+ gb). This is my current code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

def iterate_geojson(GEOJSON_FILE):
    data = gpd.read_file(GEOJSON_FILE)

    for poi in data.itertuples(index=False, name='Item'):
        print(poi.my_attribute)
```

This works correctly, but the `read_file` line takes an *extremely* long time. It seems I've incorrectly assumed that Geopandas would be smart enough not to slowly load the entire file into memory, but rather stream over the file. I've also tried reading only a subset with `gpd.read_file(GEOJSON_FILE, rows=200)`. No significant change.

So what is the correct way to efficiently IO here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There's likely a vectorized solution possible

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I'm validating and transfering all the data from geojson files to a nosql database. It works fine, except for the aforementioned issue.

Comment: the default behavior of gpd.read_json is to read in the whole file - it's not a lazy reading method or anything. As described in the [geopandas.read_file docs](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html), the read is actually done by [fiona.open](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fiona.html#fiona.open). You could open the file with fiona and iterate through the objects if the file is too large to parse at once.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I'm not sure how using fiona would help here. According to the docs, Geopandas.read_file is already mapped to fiona.open. Is there some IO vectorization functionality that fiona has which is hidden from geopandas?

Comment: Your question is about reading iteratively and the only way to do that is by using a lower-level library, such as Fiona, since geopandas loads the entire dataframe into memory. If you're instead trying to speed up your processing of the data, then you can ask about that, but we'll need to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado My follow-up question to you was this: How does using a lower-level library like Fiona help solve this issue? I'm looking at [the Fiona docs](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.open) and I don't see anything relevant that geopandas doesn't already do. Is there a specific fiona function or method you are referring to? What is this particular functionality called which fiona has that geopandas lacks?

Comment: unlike geopandas.read_file, fiona.open does return a [file object](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.collection.Collection) which can be iterated over as the file is read. So if you're looking to iterate through the file I/O in a chunked way, this is probably the best place to start. Optimizing the full workflow will depend on your full use case, but if you're running into memory constraints when parsing the geojson object, and dumping into swap or something, then reading in chunks could definitely help.